# geolocation does not work in android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I have a problems, I would like to use the geolocalisation with googleMap. I didn't have problems's with google map, just,, the geolocalisation didn't run and the value for latitude and longitude are null

```
public void geolocalisation() {
    lmanager  = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

     lmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000l, 10l, new LocationListener(){
            public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
                 latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
                 longitude = arg0.getLongitude();
            } 
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {} 
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {} 
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
        });
    GeoPoint position = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(longitude),microdegrees(latitude));

    MonOverlay marker = new MonOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.personne));//localisation point marker

    marker.addPoint(position);
    maMap.getOverlays().add(marker);
    monControler = this.maMap.getController();

}
```

and this are the permissions in the androidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS"/>
```

I doon't know what is the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue might be that the 2nd & 3rd params in your call to requestLocationUpdates. They say to sendd location updates at most every second and only if the location has changed by more than 10 meters. For most situation sitting at your dev machine, running in debug and watching logcat, moving at 10 meters a second seems unlikely.

From the API docs:

> The frequency of notification may be controlled using the minTime and
>   minDistance parameters. If minTime is greater than 0, the
>   LocationManager could potentially rest for minTime milliseconds
>   between location updates to conserve power. **If minDistance is greater
>   than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by
>   minDistance meters.** To obtain notifications as frequently as possible,
>   set both parameters to 0.

Also, I think you'll want to move the following lines into your onLocationChanged handler, otherwise they'll only get called once, not with each update;

```
GeoPoint position = new GeoPoint(microdegrees(latitude),microdegrees(longitude));

    MonOverlay marker = new MonOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.personne));//localisation point marker

    marker.addPoint(position);
    maMap.getOverlays().add(marker);
```

Comment: tank's now i move to see a new location. Just now, google map tell me i'm in afriqua, and i'm not in afriqua. 
convertir double en int java
Currently I multiply by 1000000 to get them in degrees. That wrong?

Comment: Yes, lat/long to microdegrees is * 1E6. But, your problem is that you have swapped lat and long in your new GeoPoint() call. It should be: new GeoPoint(microdegrees(latitude), microdegrees(longitude). You have them in opposite order..and it looks like I copied your reversal in my response. Fixing that in my answer.

Comment: woups i was inattentive. Now geolocalisation are good. I'm in the right place^^

Answer (score 0):

Your code is called asynchronously when location is changed, e.g. method `onLocationChanged()` is called when location is changed.

So you should put all your logic for location updates inside this method.

For the first run of the code (location changes over time, but you need to show location on map immediatelly) you should use [`lmanager.getLastKnownLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: tank's a last question how we stop the geolocalisation? I have test      lmanager.removeUpdates(this);      and the geolocalisation are still active

Comment: ok i have find to how exit the geolocalisation. I have create a LocationListener with my geolocalisation order and now i didn't have problem's